# limit on records for every date sequelize nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model which has large number of records, I want records of current month which is working fine, but it's a large data set so i want query like,
Records of October with limit of lets say 30 for every day, like there should be result per day but for every day there should be maximum 30 rows. if i put limit generally it limit to the whole data i want limit on date basis.
Here is my model query I am using sequelize

```
MyModel.findAll({
        where: {
            created_at: {
              [Op.gt]: search_from,
              [Op.lte]: search_to
            }
        },
        order: [['created_at', 'DESC']],
        limit: 30
    })
```

Here is want limit that work for every day instead if on whole records.

Comment: try group: ['created_at']

Comment: but after group, i need limit on group records. if i use group only, it adds all records which becomes more than 5000, i need 30 only